# Dell Inspiron 530 Desctop Screen Saver appears while working

Tags: windows

My Dell Desktop PC Inspiron 530 has no screen saver enabled, however the Dell logo with 'www.dell.com' appears often & stays for some time, even while working.

How can I remove this?

Comment: Why don´t you try Dell Support ? They are bound to be faster than looking around on the net.

Comment: Check msconfig for the list of Dell programs being loaded at startup, especially power-related software.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't list the version of Windows, but you could try checking the registry key for screensavers to verify they are turned off:

Go to `Start -> Run -> Regedit`

Navigate to the following registry key:
HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop. 
Value Name: ScreenSaveActive, 
Data Type: REG_SZ (String Value), 
Value Data: (0 = disabled, 1 =enabled).

Change the value of 'ScreenSaveActive' to '0' to disable the screen saver. Restart Windows for the change to take effect.

---

Another option would be to check to see if any Dell screensavers or related Dell utilities are installed and uninstall them.